# Como genero un ejecutable con pyinstaller si tengo varios modulos en distintas carpetas y una base de datos en sqlite?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy intentando crear un ejecutable con PYinstaller  de un programa hecho en Tkinter que contiene una base de datos en SQLITE, he trabajando en un entorno virtual en Pycharm, instalo en este Pyinstaller todo ok, luego creo el makespec que arroja un .spec, siguiente me voy al arhivo spec

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
INSTALANDO PYINSTALLER

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
CREANDO MAKESPEC PARA COMPILAR TODOS MIS MODULOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
AÑADIENDO MI BASE DE DATOS EN SQLITE
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A PUNTO DE EJECUTAR EL SPEC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Llego a este punto donde tendria que dar fin a la ejecucion e ir a mi carpeta DIST para buscar el ejecutable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
EJECUTO EL SPEC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Lee [ask]: en lugar de imágenes, es preferible que menciones los errores que recibes _como texto, con formato_, así haces más legible tu pregunta.

Comment: Comprueba que tu base de datos está en *dist*. Si no es así puedes copiarla manualmente o añadirla con el *flag* `--add-data "mibasedatos.db;."`. Tus módulos deben estar en *dist* o en *dist/base_library.zip* (también puedes añadirlos con `--add-data` o copiarlos manualmente en *dist*).

Comment: Puedes compilar sin `--windowed` y abrir el ejecutable desde *cmd* para ver el error.

Comment: muchas gracias por la colaboración... revisare si todos los modelos están en distancia y luego probare sin windowed efectivamente para detectar el error y comento si lo soluciono!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hice de nuevo todo, sacando el windowed y me sale lo siguiente a traves del CMD.
Creo que el error esta en los import ayuda por favor!!!!

[image: SALIDA DEL CMD]

[image: COMO TENGO ACTUALMENTE EL IMPORT DE CARPETAS]

[image: AL PARECER SERIA ASI??? PERO ME DA ERROR]

Comment: Puede que te funcione con `--hidden-import "catalogo_pelicula"`